# If $A$ and $B$ are matrices where $BA$ is a defined matrix product, find a counterexample...

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $A$ and $B$ are matrices where $BA$ is a defined matrix product,
>   find a counterexample to the claim that each column of $BA$ can we
>   written as a linear combination of the columns of $A$.
>
> Prove that each column of $BA$ can be written as a linear
>   combination of the columns of $B$.

I think I have a proof for the second claim. Namely, each column of $BA$ can be written as a vector with each component equal to the dot product of one column in $B$ with every row in $A$, and the dot product represents a linear combination.

However, I'm having trouble coming up with a counterexample to the first claim. Intuitively, it doesn't seem like every column of $BA$ can be written as a linear combination of the columns in $A$, but I haven't been able to find an instance where this is false. Can someone please help?

Comment: Is $B$ a square matrix? If not, then the question is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the counterexample: assuming $B$ needs to be square,
$$
A = \pmatrix{1\\0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}
$$
Otherwise, take any compatible $B$ that isn't square.

For the second part: suppose that $A$ has columns $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n$.  We have
$$
BA = B(A_1 \cdots A_n) = (BA_1 \cdots BA_n)
$$
It remains to be shown that for any column vector $v$, $Bv$ is a linear combination of the columns of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  Choose a matrix $A$ in which it is very easy to write down all possible linear combinations of columns of $A$.  Then choose a $B$ more or less at random.

Suggestion: in a question like this, if there are counterexamples at all, there will usually be lots of them.  Don't overthink the problem, just try something.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that $A$ and $B$ are required to be a square matrices.

Otherwise, take $B = \begin{bmatrix}1&2\end{bmatrix}$ and $A = \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix}$. There is no way to write the column of $BA = [5]$ as a linear combination of the only column of $A = \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix}$, since they don't have the same dimension.

If $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ and $A$ is invertible, then the columns of $A$ will span all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and there will be no matrix $BA$ whose columns are not a linear combination of the columns in $A$.

So, we need to choose a non-invertible matrix $A$. Let's try something simple like $A = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$. Then, if $B = \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$, we get $BA = \begin{bmatrix}a&0\\c&0\end{bmatrix}$. Can you find values of $a$ and $c$ for which this becomes a counterexample?